# fetch the uploaded image from database in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I have my upload function like this. I can upload the image but i cannot view it the blade.

**Controller**

```
public function addProduct()
{

    return view('product.add_product');
}

public function saveProduct(Request $request)
{

    $details = Input::all();

    $product_validation = new Product;
        $validation = Validator::make($details,$product_validation->setRules());


        $destinationPath = '';
        $filename        = '';

        if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
            $file            = Input::file('image');
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/';
            $filename        = str_random(6) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        }

        if($validation->fails())
            return Redirect::to('/add_product')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);

        else
        {
            $product = new Product;
            $product->product_name                  = $details['product_name'];
            $product->product_description           = $details['product_description'];
            $product->price                         = $details['price'];
            $product->image                         = $destinationPath . $filename;
            $product->date_uploaded                 = $details['date_uploaded'];
            $product->save();

        }
        return view('product.add_product');
  }
```

And here's my **view**

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/$details->image') }}" alt="{{ $details->product_name }}">
<a href="">{!! $details->product_name !!}</a></h2>
{!! $details->price !!}
```

I know that my image fetching didn't work but how can i do the right code? Hope you can help me guys. Thank you in advance. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing you images in your `public` directory and simply want to return them in your view, I would suggest using `$product->image` to store the relative path to the file.

i.e. `$product->image = '/path/to/folder' . $filename;`

You can then simply do this in your blade template by passing `$product` to the view

#### Controller

```
return view('product.add_product', [
   'product' => $product,
]);
```

#### Blade View

```
<img src="{{ $product->image }}">
```

Comment: i've got an error sir `Undefined variable: product (View: C:\IT\laravel\resources\views\product\cartpage.blade.php)`

Comment: I've follow your codes sir for the paths and not changing my view and it works sir...thank you... ^^